# How to troubleshoot logout not working?

Tags: 14.04, logout

I'm on Trusty and I have been having this annoying problem with logout since 13.x release. It always works hit or miss when I try to logout from the Log Out menu. When it doesn't work, nothing happens to my session. Any idea how I can troubleshoot this issue and find out what preventing it to log out?

Comment: Perhaps there is something useful in the [lightdm](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM) logs -> `/var/log/lightdm/` or in the `/var/log/syslog`